# Chokidar UNKNOWN error when running react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, chokidar

I used `react-slingshot` ([link](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot)) as my starter kit (which uses `create-react-app` as the base).
Recently, I've got errors log when run script `npm start` on my project. I took some research on github as well as stack over flow but it seems these errors are the rare case.

```
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\assign): Error:
UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\getUTCISOWeekYear):
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\getUTCDayOfYear):
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\requiredArgs):
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\setUTCDay): Error:
UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\getUTCWeekYear):
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\getUTCWeek): Error:
UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\protectedTokens):
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-fns\esm_lib\getUTCISOWeek):
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
Error from chokidar (D:\projects\product-travel-ui\node_modules\date-
fns\esm_lib\startOfUTCISOWeekYear): Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
```

The errors log is too long and it logs for all my library that I used in my project.
After these lines appear in the terminal, our project can not be hot-reloaded and I had to restart it manually.

Any idea about these errors ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was resolved by moving the project to C drive. Maybe it has to do with file priviledges?